# How to set time to 2 days after the current time with shell script in Solaris?

Tags: linux, shell, solaris

I would like to modify the system time to two days after but I only find that I can set the time to a specific time with the `date` command in Solaris:

```
#date mmddhhmmYY
```

but cannot add two days on the current time. Is there an easy way to do this task with a shell command? If you know something similar in linux, please also share with me.

Comment: not sure how much of the following commands are POSIX / Linux only.  But, does this command work?  `date +%m%d%H%M%Y`.  If this works, then you can write something like: `date $(date +%m%d%H%M%Y)` or `date \`date +%m%d%H%M%Y\``.  In linux, you would be able to do this too: `date -d "now + 2 days"` Don't forget to run this with the root account, if needed.

Comment: @yftse How does this add 2 days?

Comment: You will need to convert the current date to timestamp, then add 2*86400 to it, then convert it back to mmddhhmmYY format. Since I don't have access to Solaris, I will leave the rest to you, but man date should help you with both conversions

Comment: @Gavriel, you're right.  added the "+2 days" in edit.  thanks.

Comment: @user172261, if both of the above conditions work, try something like this: `date $(date -d "now + 2 days" +%m%d%H%M%Y)`

Comment: You don't need the current time (or `now`) to use `+2 days`. Just `date -d '+2 days'` works fine.

Comment: @EtanReisner not with OpenSolaris date, it doesn't. `date: illegal option -- d` (Just tried it on a freshly downloaded `tnarik/solaris10-minimal` vagrant box.)

Comment: @kojiro Fair enough (though that's not knowing about `-d` not not needing `now`). Does OpenSolaris date support the `+ 2 days` syntax at all?

Comment: @EtanReisner No. (Well, technically, it does in that it thinks it's a format string and prints '2 days'.)

Answer (score 5):

Solaris [date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9dc/index.html) supports a syntax that gradually adjusts the time. This may be your best bet.

```
date -a $(( 48 * 60 * 60 * 60 ))
```

should *eventually* update your date to two days ahead. That is really the best way to set the system time as it will gradually update instead of jumping ahead suddenly (which can screw up a bunch of running programs).

Barring that, you could write up a nice script that's aware of the days in a month, and leap years, and do the calculations yourself. If you're exceptionally lazy (like me) and precision and race conditions don't bug you that much (like me, answering StackOverflow questions), you could just do a hack like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date +%H%M.%S) # current time
date 2359.59 # Set time to 11:59:59pm
sleep 1 # Wait a second so the day rolls over
date 2359.59 # Set time to 11:59:59pm
sleep 1 # Wait a second so the day rolls over
date "$now" # Set time back to what it was, but in the new day
date -a 2 # Gradually add two seconds back to the clock
```

Test run on a `tnarik/solaris10-minimal` Vagrant box:

```
# ./adddaystodate
The current date is now Monday, 25 January 2016 00:46:59 GMT
Monday, 25 January 2016 23:59:59 GMT
Tuesday, 26 January 2016 23:59:59 GMT
Wednesday, 27 January 2016 00:46:59 GMT
The current date is now Wednesday, 27 January 2016 00:46:59 GMT
```